# HttpSelfHostServer not binding to hostname

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, asp.net-web-api

I am working with the `HttpSelfHostServer` with `asp net mvc 4 web api`

When I create the server, I specify a base address, usually somthing like `http://foo.com:8080`

Lets just say that this server has multiple ips `10.0.0.0`, `10.0.0.1`, `10.0.0.2`

we will also say that

- `http://foo.com` points to `10.0.0.0`
- `http://bar.com` points to `10.0.0.1`
- `http://baz.com` points to `10.0.0.2`

if the HttpSelfHostServer is bound to `http://foo.com:8080` why can I still access it at `http://bar.com:8080` and `http://baz.com:8080`

here is the code that instantiates the server

```
    public Server(string name, Uri baseAddress)
    {
        Name = name;
        TimeCreated = DateTime.Now;
        BaseAddress = baseAddress;
        var config = new HttpSelfHostConfiguration(BaseAddress);

        config.Routes.MapHttpRoute(
            name: "DefaultApi",
            routeTemplate: "api/{controller}/{id}",
            defaults: new {id = RouteParameter.Optional}
            );

        // Create server
        _server = new HttpSelfHostServer(config);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can modify this behavior by changing the HostNameComparisionMode property on HttpSelfHostConfiguration. By default, the value is StrongWildCard.

config.HostNameComparisonMode = System.ServiceModel.HostNameComparisonMode.StrongWildcard;

You can read more about this setting here:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.servicemodel.hostnamecomparisonmode.aspx

Comment: Spot on. Exactly what I needed.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are all three addresses are going to 127.0.0.1 Did you try accessing them from a different machine?

Comment: These requests are all from remote machines.